# Create a background process in php

Tags: php, process

I am working on a website where we want users able to create new processes on the server and interact with the server. For example, the user wants to run the C code:

```
#include<sdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

In the server, we create a process and keep it alive until the process stops running. When using functions like `exec`, we cannot do `scanf` thing. When using `proc_open`, we cannot keep the child process alive.. or we can but we don't know how..

The procedure can be: user sends instruction -> server creates a new process to do the instruction -> when doing the instruction, server sends `stdout` to the web page and gets `stdin` from the user's input -> process stops running..

Comment: Feels like a `WebSocket` job...

Comment: Gearman in combination with Supervisor might do the job and/or something like RabbitMQ/ZeroMQ for an async communication between the webserver and other components.

Comment: @Passerby is it possible to create a subprocess that can keep running? how can the subprocess run the codes above without using `proc_open`, `exec`, `popen`, etc... I haven't tried `WebSocket`..

Comment: @jamie0726 it's not quite just a communicating thing, but keep the subprocess running after running the shell user gives.. it's a little bit different from gear man..

Comment: @dahui The problem is not running process "at the background"; it's that the process has to keep interacting with user, so the user has to keep a live connection with server. HTTP protocol is primary a request-and-response style, which is not very good at that.

Comment: @Passerby here is what I want to do: use a web socket server to listen to requests. When a request about running the code comes, the server creates a subprocess to run the code and the server stores the `PID` of that subprocess. When user wants to interact, the server just put the input stream to `stdin` of the subprocess in `/proc/<pid>/fd` which I know is not so good a method.. so it's not the subprocess but the server that interacts with the user~

Comment: @dahui That sounds right. `Node.js` may do a better job here.

Comment: @Passerby Yep. But this is only part of our website and we've already finished the rest.. so it's quite difficult to change now. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a bespoke chip and pin solution that fired off a background PHP CLI script using an "&" in the exec call. The front-end and the background script then communicated by simply passing strings via 2 ascii files.
This was crude but effective. 
Obviously both processes had to check/read its incoming file, decide what to do(e.g. exeute your C++ code on the background process), then respond if necessary, by writing to its output file. Put these three steps into a loop and you have a crude listener/daemon.
This was further complicated by the background job having to simultaneously listen to a socket that was the communication channel to the authorisation service.
It was a single user scenario but could be adapted to multi-user by using unique files or writing to keyed database tables.

the call would look like this:

```
exec ("php mydaemon.php 2>&1>/dev/null &");
```

I'm assuming a Linux server - hence the linux "&" directive for run in background. The 2>&1>/dev/null just supresses stdout and stderr.

Not so sure how you would solve it in Windows - but there must be a Wscript or VBscript equivalent??

Comment: Thxs for paying attention. Actually the server is running on Ubuntu. I assume the background process can be controlled(in a way) as long as its PID is available? I don't have much knowledge about the linux system:(